# Periodically pause and resume processes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm writing a program in Python that defines a function which is basically a while True loop, runs it in 4 processes using multiprocessing module. What I want to achieve is, firstly, run the 1st process and pause the 3 others, then after 5 seconds, pause the 1st and run the 2nd, then after another 5 seconds, pause the 2nd and run the 3rd, and so on.
I read about multiprocessing.Event.set(), wait() and clear() functions but they don't seem to be very clear to me, especially wait() and clear() which both pause processes (correct me if I'm wrong).

I wrote this code, but 4 processes seem to be executed at the same time:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def function(process_name, N, events):
    while True:
        print(f"{process_name} process is running")
        time.sleep(5)
        for i in range (len(events)):
            if i == N:
                events[i].set()     # Continue the Nth process
            else:
                events[i].wait()        # Pause all the other processes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    events = []
    for i in range(4):
        events.append(multiprocessing.Event())      # Create 4 event objects for 4 processes
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=("Process 0", 0, events))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=("Process 1", 1, events))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=("Process 2", 2, events))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=("Process 3", 3, events))

    p1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p3.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p4.start()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The result is that all the processes seem to be running at the same time.

And if someone can do the same thing with threading, I'll be so thankful.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use multiprocessing.Event() to synchronize the processes, but the way you're using it in your function doesn't help to achieve your intended behavior. Calling Event.wait() in a process simply blocks the process until Event.set() is called, but in your code, all processes are running Event.wait() and Event.set() at the same time.

You can try using `Pipe`

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def function(process_name, control_pipe):
    while True:
        print(f"{process_name} is running.")
        time.sleep(5)
        control_pipe.send(process_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    control_pipes = [multiprocessing.Pipe(False) for _ in range(4)]
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(f"Process {i}", control_pipes[i][1])) for i in range(4)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for _, pipe_out in control_pipes[1:]:
        pipe_out.recv()

    while True:
        for i in range(4):
            # Wait for the current process to signal that it's done
            control_pipes[i][0].recv()
            # Signal the next process to start
            control_pipes[(i + 1) % 4][1].send('go')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code gives the same result. All the processes print out at the same moment. Anyway I'll look into Pipe, thank you for the suggestion.